# How are hooks implemented?

Tags: 8, hooks, event-subscribers

Are hooks a thing in their own right, or are they actually implemented as events under the hood?

Answer (score 2):

Hooks aren't Symfony events. They are PHP functions with a specific name that Drupal calls in very specific cases.

For example, `hook_cron()` is invoked when Drupal cron tasks are executed, from [`Cron::invokeCronHandlers()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Cron.php/function/Cron%3A%3AinvokeCronHandlers/8.6.x), which uses the following code.

```
  // Iterate through the modules calling their cron handlers (if any):
  foreach ($this->moduleHandler
    ->getImplementations('cron') as $module) {
    if (!$module_previous) {
      $logger
        ->notice('Starting execution of @module_cron().', [
        '@module' => $module,
      ]);
    }
    else {
      $logger
        ->notice('Starting execution of @module_cron(), execution of @module_previous_cron() took @time.', [
        '@module' => $module,
        '@module_previous' => $module_previous,
        '@time' => Timer::read('cron_' . $module_previous) . 'ms',
      ]);
    }
    Timer::start('cron_' . $module);

    // Do not let an exception thrown by one module disturb another.
    try {
      $this->moduleHandler
        ->invoke($module, 'cron');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
      watchdog_exception('cron', $e);
    }
    Timer::stop('cron_' . $module);
    $module_previous = $module;
  }
```

A module whose machine name is *spam_checker* could implement this hook adding the following function to its code.

```
function spam_checker_cron() {
  // Delete the nodes from the list of nodes to check after 96 hours are passed.
  Drupal::database()
    ->delete('spam_checker_list')
    ->condition('timestamp', REQUEST_TIME - 3600 * 96, '<')
    ->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They're not events (think you have symfony in mind), they are called like here in EntityStoreBase:

```
// Call hook_TYPE_load().
foreach ($this->moduleHandler()->getImplementations($this->entityTypeId . '_load') as $module) {
  $function = $module . '_' . $this->entityTypeId . '_load';
  $function($entities);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, I would say the *hook system* is a naming convention that allows you to extend the Drupal functionalities.

The core of the implementation is something like this:

```
// $vars is an array with the basic page variables that Drupal provides.
$hook = 'preprocess_page';
for ($modules as $module) {
  call_user_func_array("${module}_${hook}", $vars);
}
// Now, $vars could have new variables or a number of modifications.
// You have effectively tampered the default workflow,
// without changing the code in the Drupal Core.
```

**Hooks as a Software Engineering Design Pattern**

According to the Drupal 4 Documentation ([Programming from an Object-Oriented Perspective](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21oop.html/4.7.x))
Hooks are the procedural equivalents of the Abstraction and Inheritance OOP Concepts and the Decorator, Observer and Command Design Patterns.

This view seems to be well accepted:

- [Observer Pattern Logic Without OOP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356275/observer-pattern-logic-without-oop/3356290#3356290)
- [Best way to allow plugins for a PHP application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42/best-way-to-allow-plugins-for-a-php-application)

Other sources say the *Hooks are an implementation of the Mediator pattern*.  Mediator pattern [Hooks vs. Events](https://alanstorm.com/drupal_module_hooks/)

**Object Oriented Programming is the Future, not Hooks**

Implementing a Form, Block or Content Entity is easier and cleaner with the new Object Oriented model in Drupal 8. The related hooks were removed.

Some other removed hooks are: hook_watchdog, hook_boot, hook_init, and hook_exit.

Related Issues and links:

- Use Symfony EventDispatcher for hook system ([issue 1509164](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1509164))
- Add a HookEvent ([Issue 1972304](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1972304))
- Dispatch the PREPARE_ROW event. Deprecate prepare_row_alter hooks ([Issue 2952291](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2952291))
- Hook Event Dispatcher [Contrib module](https://www.drupal.org/project/hook_event_dispatcher)
- [Drupal 8 Hooks Unravelled](https://x-team.com/blog/drupal-8-hooks/)